# Swift - Cannot reference a local function with capture from another function

Tags: function, swift, syntax-error

i'm trying to create a vary simple game on Swift based on Balloons.playground (that Apple showed on WWDC). There is code that Apple provides:

```
func fireCannon(cannon: SKNode) {
    let balloon = createRandomBalloon()
    displayBalloon(balloon, cannon)
    fireBalloon(balloon, cannon)
}

let leftBalloonCannon = scene.childNodeWithName("//left_cannon")!
let left = SKAction.runBlock { fireCannon(leftBalloonCannon) }
```

I do the same (i suppose):

```
func displayFruit(xPos: CGFloat) -> Void {
    let fruit = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Banana")
    fruit.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    fruit.position = CGPoint(x:xPos, y: 800)
    fruit.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: fruit.texture, size: fruit.size)
    fruit.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true       
    self.addChild(fruit)
}

let start = SKAction.runBlock { displayFruit(100) }
```

This code above i put at `override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)`

I get an error: Cannot reference a local function with capture from another function

I know there was very the same questions, but solutions there don't seemed helpful for me.
What would be the right way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a local function:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    func displayFruit() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is not a local function:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // ...
}
func displayFruit() {
    // ...
}
```

Make it look like the second one.